# Is there an efficient way to sort the results of a join in RethinkDB?

Tags: sorting, rethinkdb

In RethinkDB, I need to perform a join between two tables (representing a has-and-belongs-to-many relationship) and then sort the results of the join. There could be hundreds of thousands or even millions of results, so I need to sort them efficiently.

Ideally, I would like to use `orderBy()` with an index. But [`orderBy()` can only use an index when called on a table](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#order_by), and [`.eqJoin()` returns a stream or an array](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/eq_join/).

Here’s an example of the query I’m working with. I want to get conversations that have a given topic:

```
r.table('conversations_topics')
  .getAll('c64a00d3-1b02-4045-88e7-ac3b4fee478f', {index: 'topics_id'})
  .eqJoin('conversations_id', r.table('conversations'))
  .map(row => row('right'))
  .orderBy('createdAt')
```

The unindexed `orderBy()` used here starts getting unacceptably slow when a topic contains a few thousand conversations, and will break completely at 100,000 due to RethinkDB's array size limit. Topics in this DB could easily contain many hundreds of thousands, or even millions, of conversations, so this is unacceptable.

I only need this query to return a small number of results at a time (say 25), but I need those results in order, so I can’t limit until after I sort. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think another way is to remove `conversations_topics` and embed topic data into `conversations` table. With that we can create an compound index, then use between to do `filter` and `order` at same time.

```
r.table('conversations').indexCreate('topicAndDate', function(doc) {
  return doc('topics')
    .map(function(topic) {
      return [topic, doc('createdAt')]
    })
    .coerceTo('array')
}, {multi: true})
```

Then you can use sth like this query:

```
r.table('conversations').between([('c64a00d3-1b02-4045-88e7-ac3b4fee478f', r.minval], [('c64a00d3-1b02-4045-88e7-ac3b4fee478f', r.maxval], {index: 'topicAndDate'})
  .orderBy({index: r.desc('topicAndDate')})
  .limit(25)
```

The key here is that we use same index for both of  `orderBy` and `between`. If you know the time range, it can make even faster by setting time value in `between` command instead of using `minval` and `maxval`.

Hopefully it will be faster.